# Why my EntityA contains EntityB, but not EntityB contains EntityA?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

I....recreated my entity model and database couples of time....already tried to figures out whole day....

I have a 3 tables, Client, Campaign and Campaign_Url.

So the relationship is,

- A Client can have many Campaign (1 to *)
- Mutiple Campaign can have same Campaign_Url (* to 1)

So the Campaign table has two foregin key

- Campaign.url_id is foregin key to Campaign_Url.campaign_url_id
- Campaign.client_id is foregin key to Client.client_id

As shown in:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Campaign]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Campaign_Campaign] FOREIGN KEY([url_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Campaign_Url] ([campaigin_url_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Campaign] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Campaign_Campaign]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Campaign]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Campaign_Client] FOREIGN KEY([client_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Client] ([client_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Campaign] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Campaign_Client]
GO
```

So everything is good, I can left join and show data properly.
I can create the data model by generates the data model from database.

It gives me a model I am expecting:

[image]

Then I try to run the following piece of code to see if data is populate properly from entity framework:

```
    using (MyEntities dataContext = new MyEntities())
    {
        int totalClient = dataContext.Client.Count();    
        foreach (Client aClient in dataContext.Client)
        {
            int total = aClient.Campaign.Count();   //<===== here is return 0 campagin
        }
        foreach (Campaign aCampaign in dataContext.Campaign)
        {
            string abc = aCampaign.Client.name;  //<====== here the campaign did return the client name
        }

    }
```

So that's strange, Client.Campaign doesn't contains any Campaign.
But when I go from Campaign.Client I will able to get its Client....

What did I done wrong?  When I left join it in sql it returns correctly, and I double checked the foregin key and data, it is correct....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, populating one-to-many relationships does not work with entity framework. You have to go the nasty way and populate the relations one by one.

Comment: It does work, but you need to have Lazy Loading and Proxies enable for it to be "automagic".  Otherwise you need to explicitly load the properties.

Comment: @CodingGorilla ah, so is that what I am missing?  I am trying to enable the Lazy Loading.... like from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456846.aspx  But... I can't find ContextOption property from context... Please tell me .NET 3.5 has it....?

Comment: @KingChan I think it does (I don't remember) but it was different in 3.5, and as I recall Da_Wolf might be right in that it doesn't work quite right.  I wasn't a big fan of EF until 4, so I didn't do a lot with 3.5.

Comment: @CodingGorilla I would get it working like Da_Wolf said, do in nasty way like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216251/entity-framework-lazy-loading-in-net-3-5  It seems EF1 in 3.5 have to do it this way..